# Need help understanding UIViewController and UIWindow initialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigationcontroller

I was wondering if anyone could explain the following block of code because I don't really understand it.

```
self.viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navigationController = [[ UINavigationController alloc ] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController ];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Then when you want to present a new vc you can do this:

```
OtherViewController *ovc = [[ OtherViewController alloc ] initWithNibName:@"OtherViewController" bundle:nil ];
[ self.navigationController pushViewController:ovc animated:YES ];
```

To go back do this:

```
[ self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES ];
```

Comment: What don't you understand, specifically? That's fairly old-school code using XIB files rather than storyboards, but it seems self-expanatory to me.

Comment: What do the first four lines do? I know the last three are for creating the navigationController and navigating between viewControllers.

Comment: the first four are the constructors/initialization code for those elements as well as assignments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A navigation controller needs a "root" view controller, which is the bottom view controller in the stack of view controllers it manages.

```
#1 self.viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
#2 self.navigationController = [[ UINavigationController alloc ] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController ];
#3 self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
#4 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Line 1 creates a view controller of class "RootViewController" (which must be a custom view controller class.) It loads the view controller's views from a nibfile of the same name. This is similar to using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier to load a view controller from a storyboard, except that you have to specify the class of view controller you're creating, and the nibfile you're loading the

Line 2 creates a navigation controller with the newly created "RootViewController" as it's root view controller

Line 3 installs the navigation controller as the root view controller of the application window.

Line 4 makes the app window the active window.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation in simple words.
Every iOS Application has at least 1 `UIWindow` which always needs a `UIViewController` object to set as a root which means to set as a initial ViewController of the application that will be visible to the user on screen.
while `UINavigationController` is stack container which push ViewControllers inside it and the top ViewController in this stall will only be visible to screen by default. But initially it needs a `UIViewController` to set as a root view controller in both `UIWindow` and `UINavigationController's` root view controller they need a starting point. Both works differently like `UIWindow` root view controller can be change at any time but `UINavigationController` doesn't allow us to change root view controller.

Now in your code let me explain you what is going on.

```
self.viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
//In Above Line you are loading a UIViewController from a Xib file name RootViewController.xib into viewController property
self.navigationController = [[ UINavigationController alloc ] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController ];
//In Above Line You are allocating a new navigation controller programatically with a root/initial view controller and you are passing your previously loaded view controller to be set as root view controller of this navigation.
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
//In Above Line You are assigning your navigationController to UIWindow object this means you want your view controllers to be managed in a stack so that if you push a view controller you can snap back easily with a single line of code.
[ self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES ];
//In This Line you are removing your Top view Controller from a navigation stack Like the Back button does in Setting>General to Setting in iPhone/iPad
```